# JSON error on submit in IE7 (and only IE7): "Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON."

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2, internet-explorer-7

This is strictly an IE7 problem; IE8 doesn't mind, and neither does FF. Our form throws the following exception when submitting:

```
Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.
Parameter name: data
```

Form header (edited for secrecy; we have a paranoid NDA):

```
<%using (Ajax.BeginForm("...", "...", FormMethod.Post,
    new AjaxOptions {
       OnComplete = "OnSaveEditCommunitySuccess",
       OnBegin = "OnBegin" },
    new { id = "form_Edit...", name = "form_Edit..." }))
```

I temporarily attached a handler to OnBegin, and looked at the json object that gets passed around. I can guarantee `json.get_request().get_body()` is identical to what happens in FF, and properly web encoded:

```
ProfileTabModel.IsEdit=true&ProfileTabModel.HandEnterCommunity=true&ProfileTabModel.CommunityId=26&ProfileTabModel.County=&ProfileTabModel.OrgId=7395& (...)
```

It might be relevant that this is a large form, and the data sent is at least 2500 bytes. I realize it shouldn't matter in a POSt, and even if it would, it has nothing to do with the reported error, but best mention it, since other forms written on the same pattern have no trouble posting their data.

[EDIT:] When running on debug, IE7 doesn't enter the Action in the controller, while everything else does. Forgot to mention this.

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON?

Comment: I'd love to find it, first. I mean, I can dig through the HTTP request just fine, and I can see it never enters the action method in the controller. But I don't even know what JSON it's talking about.

Comment: You could try to alter all the json calls to log what they are trying to encode and if it succeeds add a newline with 'succes' to it

Comment: I know what's happening: the problem occurs when it's time to encode the submit button. Our buttons are generated as `<button><span> Submit</></>`; when it's time to build the request, all other browsers are smart enough to take only "Submit", but IE7 also tries to encode the `<span>`. We've had this error in other contexts, but this time I got set on a false path by the JSON error.

Comment: Different browsers parses the button tag in different ways. IE submits the value between <button> and </button>, some other browsers submit the value attribute of button tag. My guess is IE8 has changed to behavior as the latter. So if it's inside a form, it's better to use an input tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution and summary:

The problem occurs when it's time to encode the submit button. Our buttons are generated as `<button ... ><span> Submit</span></button>`; when it's time to build the request, all other browsers, IE8 included, are smart enough to take only "Submit". IE7 sends all inner HTML. We've had this error in other contexts, but this time I got set on a false path by the JSON error.

I cannot and will not change from `<% Http.Button %>` to an input; it's beyond me how this could be even considered a viable solution; that extension is used for very good reasons, and if ditching it was an option I wouldn't have asked this question in the first place.

The solution was to add a new filter, extending `RequestValidator`, and check the request for the offending `span` tag; if found, replace with the text.

```
public class HttpRequestValidator : RequestValidator
{
    protected override bool IsValidRequestString(
            HttpContext context,
            string value,
            RequestValidationSource requestValidationSource,
            string collectionKey,
            out int validationFailureIndex)
    {
        // Check if the Request.QueryString contains a post value of "<span>.....</span>"
        if (requestValidationSource == RequestValidationSource.Form
              && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.StartsWith("<span>",
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(value, @"\A<span>(.*?)</span>\Z",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 1)
                return base.IsValidRequestString(
                    context, match.Groups[1].Value,
                    requestValidationSource,
                    collectionKey,
                    out validationFailureIndex);

        }

        return base.IsValidRequestString(
            context,
            value,
            requestValidationSource,
            collectionKey,
            out validationFailureIndex);
    }
}
```

You'll also need to add it in `web.config`; search for `httpRuntime` and replace it with

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\"
  requestValidationType=" ... .HttpRequestValidator"
  maxRequestLength="40920" maxQueryStringLength="10000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy/paste your json code into http://jsonlint.com/ to check its validity and see the problem.

Comment: A very good link to remember, but I posted the problem with the JSON 5 days before your post, in the original post comment...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd better to use a normal "input" tag with button type, since it's inside a form. Apparently IE 7 takes the button's inner html as its value, while many other browsers use the "value" attribute.

Comment: At the risk of being rude: when somebody has a problem with a controller or extension, the proper answer is never "Stop using the controller"; if this were an acceptable solution, I'd have done so and never opened the question in the first place. Never mind put a bounty on it.